# What is the opposite of Jquery .not - OR - How to I target href links that contain the following

Tags: jquery

Right. So here we go.

I am currently using the following code to target all links and apply an iframe toolbar

```
$("a[href^='http:']").not("[href*='www.domiain.com']").not("[href*='www.twitter.com']").each(function(){ 
 var tempurl = 'http://www.domain.com/shiftbar/shiftbar.html?iframe=';
 var $this = $(this);
 var currenturl = this.getAttribute("href");
    var href = tempurl + currenturl;
 $this.attr('href', href ); 
});
```

I need to do the same, but now for links that ONLY contain twitter

```
$("a[href^='http:']").contains("[href*='www.twitter.com']").each(function(){ 
 $this.attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

it doesn't work. I've tried

```
.has
.contains
```

But I suppose I am not familiar with jquery enough at this point.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a[href^='http:'][href*='www.twitter.com']")
```

or

```
$("a[href^='http://www.twitter.com']")
```

Comment: Solid. But it is being used for all outgoing twitter links (multiple twitter accounts... 

That seems to just target url 'http://www.twitter.com'

Answer (score 3):

Use .filter just like you are in your non-working example.

Comment: So $("a[href^='http:']").filter("[href*='www.twitter.com']").each(function(){ 

});

works but  $this.attr('target','_blank'); doesn't..

Comment: Done! It works

$("a[href^='http:']").filter("[href*='www.twitter.com']").attr('target','_blank');

one line, not a function. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working using

```
$("a[href^='http:']").filter("[href*='www.twitter.com']").attr('target','_blank');
```

Using the .each function seemed to bug out especially when applying the .attr

Comment: Inside the function you put into each(), $this isn't a variable unless you make it one...

$this = $(this);